# Selfmade MessageBox.Show() in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to rebuild the "look & feel" of MessageBox.Show() of WinForms applications.

**With "look & feel" I mean to JUST CALL the MessageBox.Show() command with the logic of my already implemented ShowMessage method.**

My current codebehind:

```
public partial class Testpage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public enum MessageBoxIcon { Information, Error, Warning }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ShowMessage("Testmessage", MessageBoxIcon.Error, ex);
    }

    private void ShowMessage(string title, string message, MessageBoxIcon type, Exception ex)
    {
        if (type == MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        {
            pnlMsgBox.CssClass = "MessageBoxInformation";
            imgMsgBox.ImageUrl = "Resources/img/icon/MessageBoxIcon.Information.png";
        }

        else if (type == MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
        {
            pnlMsgBox.CssClass = "MessageBoxWarning";
            imgMsgBox.ImageUrl = "Resources/img/icon/MessageBoxIcon.Warning.png";
        }

        else if (type == MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        {
            pnlMsgBox.CssClass = "MessageBoxError";
            imgMsgBox.ImageUrl = "Resources/img/icon/MessageBoxIcon.Error.png";
        }

        else
            throw new NotImplementedException();

        lblMsgBox.Text = "<span style=\"font-size: large;\">" + title + "</span><br /><br />" + message;

        #if (DEBUG)
        if (ex != null)
            lblMsgBox.Text += "<br /><br /><b>Debug information:</b> " + ex.Message;
        #endif

        pnlMsgBox.Visible = true;

        updPnl.Update();
    }
}
```

I'd like to call something like this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Testmessage", MessageBoxIcon.Error, ex);
    }
```

But

```
public static class MessageBox : Testpage
{
    public static void Show(string message)
    {
        // do stuff with the page controls.
    }
}
```

doesn't work as you all know, because Testpage isn't static.

Does anybody have some suggestions for me?

Comment: One thing you *can not* duplicate: in winforms, the MessageBox.Show blocks the code until the user clicks OK. You can't do that in asp.net.

Comment: "pnlMsgBox" is an overlay that blocks the rest of the content, that's ok for my purpose. With "look & feel" I mean to JUST CALL the MessageBox.Show() command with the logic of my already implemented ShowMessage method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the comments to the previous answer, I think next:

Its difficult to get access to current page context from the separated static class. So then, i recomendate do next:

Define next interface:

```
public interface IMessageBoxContainer
{
    UpdatePanel UpdatePanel { get; }
    Label Label { get; }
}
```

and implement him by your page as:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page, IMessageBoxContainer
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public UpdatePanel UpdatePanel
    {
        get { return updatePanel1; }
    }
    public Label Label
    {
        get { return label1; }
    }
}
```

This steps provide you to get access to your page from anywhere. After that implement you MessageBox NON-static class:

```
public class MessageBox
{
    private IMessageBoxContainer container = null;

    public MessageBox(IMessageBoxContainer _container)
    {
        container = _container;
    }

    public void Show(string message)
    {
        container.Label.Text = message;
        container.UpdatePanel.Update();
    }
}
```

Why non-static? Becouse if you do *container* field as static and set him value anywhere in page (for example in Page_Load), when another page will load - your *container* property will reset. But without this field, that pointer to your current page, you cant get access to your specefied controls.

After that you can use your class like that:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var box = new MessageBox(this);
    box.ShowMessage("hello world");
}
```

So, you get separated implementation logic of your MessageBox and simple using him, yes? But unfurtunently, its non-static.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I HAVE to deal with the non static sense. Thanks for your solution! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
public static class MessageBox
{
    public static void Show(string message)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(string.Format("<script>alert('{0}');</script>", message));
    }
}
```

Of course, you will need to implement your own correct JavaScript to display you MessageBox on client-side. But I thing – you approach is wrong. For you method programming try to look in ASP.NET  MVC, becouse classic ASP.NET do not fully support JavaScript coding.

Comment: The OP is trying to implement the *look & feel* of the WinForms MessageBox - not a JavaScript alert box.

Comment: It is wrong to say that "classic" ASP.NET (I will assume you are referring to WebForms here?) does not fully support JavaScript coding. It supports it fine with Javascript. Whilst MVC may have better integration with JS, it doesn't mean that it supports it any more than WebForms does.

Comment: Tim: I sad, that OP must implement his Javascript to display "look & feel" msgbox and implement callbacks, if he needs. But may be i uncorrectly understend question - so sorry.

Comment: @hdougie: yes, your right, i means that. My english no so good, to say, thats sad you, sory :)

Comment: I think his intent is to use a WebForm to create a *WinForm-like* MessageBox - which is quite different in look and feel from a JavaScript alert.  Perhaps the OP can clarify when he comes back.

Comment: Sorry for my bad description. "to use a WebForm to create a WinForm-like MessageBox" - That's true! My first code block shows the "logic" that needs to be done by the static MessageBox class. All I want to do is to outsource this logic (ShowMessage-Method) in a static MessageBox class. The problem: I can't use the site specific labels, textboxes, panels etc. in this static context. I have my own designed <asp:Panel> if you will that I'm showing with specific contents on MessageBox.Show().